# Add a title to an element in a specific style by js

Tags: javascript, css

I want the title I give to my element to be arranged as follows:

> 1-book1
>  2-book2 
> 3-book3 
> 4-book4

But when I give the title, it shows like this :

> 1-book1 2-book2 3-book3 4-book4

Friends, how can I style my title?

Comment: `display:block;`

Comment: Please post more details on actual code that you're using. So that it would help understand better.

Answer (score 0):

You could also put every element in a **div** tag. That should solve the problem